# Phones got unknown and unrecognized notification sound

Tags: notifications

It is not a tech question....

Few days ago I was with my friend in the same room. Suddenly my phone and my friend's phone had a notification sound almost at the same time.

We thought that we properly got whatsapp group chat messages from other common friends.

We looked at our phones and there was nothing.

What could it be??

We have both Samsung A series phones.

Comment: Could be the notification of an incoming [emergency] [Cell Broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast)

Comment: @Robert probably. Especially at the current situation...  however we did not get any "message". We are in Europe.